# Event listener on datalist (html,css.javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created this datalist, when someone chooses an option I want there to be an image appearing. To be more exact the options are greek islands, so when someone chooses one of the islands a distinctive img of that island should appear. I do not know exactly what js code to use for that event to happen.

```
<label for="epilogh-proorismou">Επιλέξτε προορισμό:</label>
<input list="epiloges" id="proorismoi" name="proorismoi" />
<datalist id="epiloges">
   <option value="Κρήτη">
   <option value="Σαντορίνη">
   <option value="Χίος">
   <option value="Πάρος">
   <option value="Κέρκυρα">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Where do you want to display images? And show html the structure of your images, pls.

Comment: If you don't want your users to be able to type something else than these values a <select> is probably better suited.

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you're looking for:

```js
function setImage(value) {
  var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img"); 
    for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
      imgs[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  document.getElementById(value).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="epilogh-proorismou">Επιλέξτε προορισμό:</label>
<input list="epiloges" id="proorismoi" onmousedown="this.value='';" onchange="setImage(this.value);"  name="proorismoi" />

<datalist id="epiloges">
    <option value="Κρήτη">
    <option value="Σαντορίνη">
    <option value="Χίος">
    <option value="Πάρος">
    <option value="Κέρκυρα">
</datalist>

<img id="Κρήτη" src="" alt="Κρήτη"></img>
<img id="Σαντορίνη" src="" alt="Σαντορίνη"></img>
<img id="Χίος" src="" alt="Χίος"></img>
<img id="Πάρος" src="" alt="Πάρος"></img>
<img id="Κέρκυρα" src="" alt="Κέρκυρα"></img>
```

Comment: I have changed the datalist to an input type radio kind of list, but i still cant make the picture shown when there is a selection

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
document.querySelector('input[list="epiloges"]').addEventListener('input', updateImage);

function updateImage(event) {
  const value = event.target.value

  // Do what you have to do with value
  console.log(value)
}
```

```html
<label for="epilogh-proorismou">Επιλέξτε προορισμό:</label>
<input list="epiloges" id="proorismoi" name="proorismoi" />

<datalist id="epiloges">
    <option value="Κρήτη">
    <option value="Σαντορίνη">
    <option value="Χίος">
    <option value="Πάρος">
    <option value="Κέρκυρα">
</datalist>
```

You can than update or create an image based on the value. If you require help with that as well comment below.

Answer (score -1):

Here you can add onchange to input and fetch data from it.

```js
function getImages(e) {
  var val = document.getElementById("browser").value;
  // here you can add fetch call
  const id = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000);
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/"+id).then((response) => response.json()).then(data => renderImage(data.url));
}

function renderImage(url) {
  const el = document.getElementById("output");
  el.innerHTML = `<img src='${url}' width=90 height=90>`;
}
```

```html
<label for="browser">Choose your browser from the list:</label>
<input list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser" onchange="getImages()">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Edge">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>

<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: The input event is probably better for this kind of selection since it fires directly when the user selects something.

Comment: I guess not as I think the main point of using datalist was to select from the option and fire rest api query. Ofcourse, input event listener is a way but you don't want to query a single character and load image from it? What use case it will achieve ?

Comment: For example- If I want to query "Edge", the API would query 'E', 'Ed', 'Edg' and then 'Edge' Ofcourse, you can add debouncing to it but I dont think the OP wanted this since he stated - "when someone chooses an option I want there to be an image appearing"